# how understand periodicity in a combination of power, gamma and zeta functions?

Tags: special-functions, riemann-zeta-function, gamma-function

Riemann's functional equation may be written:
$$
\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)} = 2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin(\frac{\pi s}2) \Gamma(1-s) \tag{1}
$$
and so by symmetry:
$$
\frac{\zeta(1-s)}{\zeta(s)} = 2^{1-s} \pi^{-s} \cos(\frac{\pi s}2) \Gamma(s) \tag{2}
$$
multiplying the two versions gives Euler's reflection formula.

now define a function
$$
\Psi(s) = (2\pi)^{-s} \Gamma(s) \zeta^2(s) 
$$
so that the result of dividing $(1)$ by $(2)$ is expressed as:
$$
\frac{\Psi(s)}{\Psi(1-s)} = \tan \frac{\pi s}2
$$

**question** is there any intuitively appealing "explanation" for this periodicity?